# socket.io, netty-socketio, nginx disconnecting every minute

Tags: javascript, nginx, websocket, socket.io, netty

I have a `netty-socketio` server running on port `9092`. `nginx` is configured to listen on port `9093` and proxy requests to the `netty-socketio` server (both are currently running on the same server but will be separate once in production).

If I connect directly to the socket server everything works as expected, however when connecting via `nginx` connections drop and reconnect every one minute.

Extremely simplified client example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://1.1.1.1:9093');

            socket.on('connect', function ()
            {
                console.log('connected to socket server');
            });

            socket.on('disconnect', function ()
            {
                console.log('lost connection to socket server');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

`nginx` config:

```
upstream socketserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:9092;
}

server {
    listen 9093;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://socketserver;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_pass_header Connection;
        proxy_pass_header Date;
    }
}
```

The only difference I could find was the `Connection: Upgrade` header was set with an uppercase "U" when connecting directly and all lowercase ("upgrade") when using `nginx`. I went as far as recompiling `nginx` from the source but having uppercase "U" didn't make a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with directives with default values of `60s` I found the culprit to be `proxy_read_timeout`. Adding this in the `server` context fixed the problem for me:

```
proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
```

Documentation on this directive [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_read_timeout).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `keepalive` in the upstream portion.

```
...
keepalive 60;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't make any difference.